# React semantic-ui - Closable menu tabular / tab

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

```
<Menu tabular>
 {
  menus.map((menu, index) => (
   <Menu.Item 
    key={index} 
    name={menu.name} 
    active={this.props.location.pathname === menu.path} 
    onClick={() => {this.props.handleOpenClick(menu)}} 
   >
    {menu.name}
    <Button onClick={() =>  {this.props.handleCloseClick(index)}}>X</Button>
   </Menu.Item>
  ))
 }
</Menu>
```

I want to create a dynamic tabular layout with closable feature by using `Menu` and `tabular` option. I put the `Button` component inside a `Menu.Item` and implement the onClick event. 
When the buton is clicked, it's also calling `handleOpenClick()` function on the `Menu.Item` component. I need to call the `handleCloseClick()` only.

Is there any suggestion ?

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **e.stopPropagation()**.

```
<Menu tabular>
{
menus.map((menu, index) => (
    <Menu.Item 
        key={index} 
        name={menu.name} 
        active={this.props.location.pathname === menu.path} 
        onClick={() => {this.props.handleOpenClick(menu)}} 
    >
        {menu.name}
        <Button onClick={e =>  {
            e.stopPropagation();
            this.props.handleCloseClick(index);
        }}>X</Button>
    </Menu.Item>
    ))
}
</Menu>
```